# SqlAlchemy Polymorphism create parent and child tables independently

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a polymorphic association set up like below:

```
class Parent(Base)
      id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
      name = Column(String, nullable=False)


class Child(Parent)
      parent_id = Column(ForeignKey(Parent.id), primary_key=True)
      description = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'child'
    }
```

I would like to be able to first create the parent table, and then link it to the child table like so:

```
parent = Parent(name='foobar')
session.add(parent)
session.flush()
child = Child(description='baz', parent_id=parent.id)
```

However I receive an integrity error on the `name` field null constraint on the child creation - meaning that last line attempts to insert into the parent table as well.

Is there a way to achieve this split inserts?

Comment: SQLAlchemy doesn't provide a good way of changing the polymorphic identity (aka type) of an object. Why do you need to do this?